# Using if then with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup

I have a dataset using pandas in python and would like to apply an if-then-else rule for a specific column.

If the there is missing value, then replace it with a specific value taken from another column in the same observation, else do nothing.

My dataset is generated by the code as follow:

`results = df2.merge(df1,on="sku", how="left")`

The column variable that needs to be filled, if empty is "stock_y". 
If empty, the value of the column variable "stock_x" should be copied to "stock_y". In the case that stock_y is already filled, the code should skip the observation.

Comment: Look into fillna.  Ps your post will probably be downvoted if you don't post sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`Series.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
results['stock_y'] = results['stock_y'].combine_first(results['stock_x'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation with `fillna`:

```
results['stock_y'] = results['stock_y'].fillna(results['stock_x'])
```